# Adding a generic value to a generic container of a unknown type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

is there a way to add the animal to the cage? :)

```
public class Cage<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public final String name = "foo";
}
```

---

```
public Zoo {
    List<? extends Cage<?>> zooCages= new ArrayList<Cage<?>>();

    public <T> void addAnimal(String name, T animal){
           for(Cage<?> c : zooCages)
               if(c.name.equals(name)){
                  c.add(animal);       //compile error
                  return;
               }
     }
}
```

EDIT: Typos.
EDIT 2 : complete the example

Comment: That rather depends on the declaration of Cage and its add method.  Is it just a subclass of a collection?

Comment: You're missing parentheses for the constructor call on line 1., and a semicolon after `c.add(animal)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the use of unbounded wildcards. See the following example:

```
Cage<?> cage1 = new Cage<Integer>();
Cage<?> cage2 = new Cage<String>();
Cage<?> cage3 = new Cage<T>();

someMethod(cage1);
someMethod(cage2);
someMethod(cage3);

public void someMethod(Cage<?> cage) {
  cage.add(1);                // Will not compile
  cage.add("A String");       // Will not compile
  cage.add(someValueOfTypeT); // Will not compile
}
```

Technically, the method wasn't strictly necessary, but you can easily see the problem with this code. A `Cage<?>` can be a `Cage<String>` or a `Cage<Anything>`. You can't add anything to it because it could be any specific Cage.

If you want to add `T` to a `Cage` it has to be a `Cage<T>` or a `Cage<? super T>`. One way you can do this is:

```
public class Zoo<T> {
  private List<? extends Cage<? super T>> cages = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addAnimal(String cageName, T animal) {
    for(Cage<? super T> cage : cages) {
      // Now you can add animal to a cage
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming `Cage` is a collection.)

You have a conceptual error here.

`c` is declared in the foreach loop as a `Cage<?>`, i.e. a cage that accepts an unspecified type. You are trying to add an object of type `T` to it, but there's no reason to believe that `c` can contain objects of type `T`.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html for details on what the wildcard `*` means.

You probably wanted all the cages in the class to contain the same (arbitrary) type `T`. In this case, the entire enclosing class should take a type parameter. For example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main<T> {
    private class Cage extends ArrayList<T> {
        public final String name = "foo";
    }

    List<? extends Cage> zooCages = new ArrayList<Cage>();

    public void addAnimal(String name, T animal) {
        for(Cage c : zooCages) {
             if(c.name.equals(name)) {
                 c.add(animal);
                 return;
             }
        }
    }
}
```